# Point Cloud Processing algorithm for QGIS 3.30

Tags: qgis, point-cloud

Has anyone installed the new Point Cloud processing capability in QGIS that was announced recently? Apparently it is in the Github Master but I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This facility will be released in QGIS 3.32. I have found it in the beta but waiting for the final release before I try it.